# Why I am I getting "A get or set accessor expected" here?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

On the annotated line below, why am I getting the error

> A get or set accessor expected

???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SingleLinkedList
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    public class SingleLinkedList<T>
    {
        private class Node
        {
            T Val;
            Node Next;
        }

        private Node _root = null; 

        public T this[int index]
        {
            for(Node cur = _root; // error pointing to here
                index > 0 && cur != null; 
                --index, cur = cur.Next);

            if(cur == null)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            return cur.Val;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Consult your favorite C# language book about indexers.   It is a property like any property, just with a funny name.  And properties have a get and set accessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a getter:

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get 
    {
        for(Node cur = _root;
            index > 0 && cur != null; 
            --index, cur = cur.Next);

        if(cur == null)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        return cur.Val;
    }
}
```